# When multi-threading is a bad idea?

Tags: multithreading

According to the way i understand threads, programming a multi-threaded program either can speed up the program or just match the  execution time of a single-threaded version of the program.

So, my two questions are:

1- Is what i said true or false ?

2- give example when multi-threading code produce negative results on performance ?

Answer (score 1):

A multi-threaded program can behave worse than a single-threaded equivalent. This is primarily due to:

- The cost to initially create additional threads
- The cost of context switches
- The potential for [false sharing](http://www.drdobbs.com/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-a/223100705).

Creating many threads that do a small amount of work that alters adjacent regions of memory would likely exhibit all of those issues.

Multi-threaded programs in general introduce additional complexity and present numerous opportunities for bugs. That should also be taken into account when deciding whether or not to use multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks Eric, that was helpful !

Answer (score 0):

1-True in general, false in rare cases.
2-example:

you have only one CPU core while no blocking/wait on any thread. There is necessarily waste of CPU time to coordinate multi threads. Since only one thread can run although they all could, (hence the non-blocking/non-waiting condition), the total time is higher.